# What shall the characteristic of K be for the identity (1) to be valid?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $K$ be a field.
Let $f$ be a linear operator on $V$. Consider the identity:
$v=1/2(v+f(v))+1/2(v-f(v))$ (1)

Suppose, $f$ is such that for any $v$ in $V$, one has: $f(f(v))=v$

What shall the characteristic of $K$ be for the identity (1) to be valid?

I define characteristic of field $K$ to be: the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $n\cdot1=0$ or $0$ if no such integer exists.

I found that applying $f$ to both sides and using that $f$ is a linear operator, allows the equation to be simplified. But cannot understand what is needed to show the characteristic of $K$.

Applying f to both sides we get:

$f(v)=f(1/2(v+f(v))+1/2(v-f(v)))$

Since $f$ is a linear operator, we have $f(av+bw)=af(v)+bf(w)$, therefore

$f(v)=\frac12(f(v)+\frac12f(f(v))+\frac12f(v)-\frac12f(f(v))$, this cancels to

$f(v)=\frac12(2f(v))$

Would the characteristic for part be $2<char(k)$ for the identity to be valid?

Comment: But f(f(v))=v is only hypothesized, it's not an identity. Are you sure "(1)" isn't the identity you wrote in the first line? That requires the characteristic not be two, since that's what lets us divide by two.

Comment: Sorry, yes you are correct, the identity (1) is in the 1st line.